# Add User Module to existing MariaDB Columnstore Cluster

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I have a MariaDB Columnstore Cluster of one User Module and two Permormance Modules. (UM1, PM1 and PM2)
Now I want to add a second User Module (UM2) which connects to the PM1 and PM2.

Do I have to install all four Modules from ground, or can I just install MariaDB Columnstore on UM2 and refer towards UM1 and PM1 and PM2, without installing software on UM1, PM1 and PM2?

(UM1, PM1 and PM2 are in production, so there for the can not be re-installed)

Comment: Do's anybody know an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/managing-columnstore-module-configurations/#addmodule-command), a User Module can be added to MariaDB ColumnStore. I highly recommend testing the addModule procedure on your test environment first.